# Getting a power spectrum on data with an irregular time base

Tags: signal-processing, fft, astronomy

I have an array of `charlie = array ([ [time, value], [time ,value] , [time,value], ...etc])`.  The time intervals are not regular.

I am not yet sufficiently familiar with sp = np.fft.fft( charlie ), or similar, to crack the nut on my own.

How can I extract the periodic feature of the values over time and then plot it in an easy to read form?

Comment: I recommend phrasing your question in the form of a question.

Comment: Opps, somebody edited out the bit which asked the question, whilst leaving the context for the question.

Comment: There, does that summarize exactly what you mean to ask?

Comment: Well thank you very much indeed.

Comment: see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/32761   same question, see references shown there. See this also http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-do-i-take-the-fft-of-unevenly-spaced-data and many more. It is amazing what can find with simple google search before asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a discrete Fourier transformation with non equal time steps.

Asume you have N data pairs: (t0, x0), (t1, x1), ... (tN-1, xN-1).

[image: Fourier transformation with non equal time steps]

The order of time has to be monotonic increasing: t0 < t1, t1 < t2, ..., tN-2 < tN-1

For a FFT the data set is interpreted as one period of a periodic function, so xN = x0 and tN = t0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a polynomial interpolator to interpolate a set of equal time spaced samples, before you use an FFT.